# Failing to pass data from client (JS) to server (Flask) with Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

First time ever using jQuery to pass a dictionary filled through a JS script to my server written in Python (Flask) when the user hits a submit button (I read somewhere that AJAX was the way to go).

Something must be broken since in the server function described below, request.get_data() or request.form are None. If any seasoned programmer could give recommendation on how to set up a jQuery request, it would be much appreciated.

In Python, I have the following:

```
@app.route('/submit',methods=['POST'])
def submit():
     info = request.form['info']
     action = request.form['action']
     ...
```

To handle the dictionary info. On my html file, I load AJAX through:

```
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
```

Define my "submit" button as followed:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="send(event,'s')" id="SUBMIT">Submit</button>
```

And handle the action through the script:

```
<script>
var dict = [];
function send(event,action) {
    $.post('/submit', {
        info: dict,
        action: action
    }).done(function() {
    }).fail(function() {
});
}
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert request.form to dictionary and print it you can able get the values

```
print(request.form.to_dict())
```

Comment: Why would that change anything? I tried your fix but in the server, request.form is still empty